# Intercept private annotated method with AOP

Tags: java, aop

I have a custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FeatureSwitch {

    String featureName();

}
```

I intercept this with the below aspect and use it to check if a feature is on or off. If the feature is off, then I throw an exception.

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class FeatureSwitchAspect {

    private final FeatureSwitchConfigurationApi featureSwitchConfigurationApi;

    public FeatureSwitchAspect(final FeatureSwitchConfigurationApi featureSwitchConfigurationApi) {
        this.featureSwitchConfigurationApi = featureSwitchConfigurationApi;
    }

    @Before("@annotation(featureSwitch)")
    public void checkFeatureSwitch(final FeatureSwitch featureSwitch) {
        final String featureName = featureSwitch.featureName();
        Boolean featSwitch = featureSwitchConfigurationApi.isFeatureActive(featureName);
        if (!featSwitch) {
            throw new FeatureSwitchOffException();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the behaviour seems inconsistent. This seems to do as expected when I call a method from a different class, but if I make a call to an annotated private method, no interception occurs. Have I got it configured incorrectly? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on your aop solution you are using proxies. IN that case only method calls INTO the object are intercepted as they pass through the proxy. Internal calls don't pass through the proxy. If you want interception of internal method calls you have to setup load or compile time weaving for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will have to think of an alternative for calls to methods inside a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged your question by *java* and *aop*, not by *spring* or *spring-aop*. So I assume that you are not limited to proxy-based Spring AOP but can use a full-fledged AOP solution like AspectJ (possible even within Spring or application servers). If so, there is a solution:

Use a [privileged aspect](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#aspect-privilege). Caveat: This is supported in native AspectJ syntax, but [not in @AspectJ syntax](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspects.html#limitations).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. This looks promising. How is this initialised? Component scanning doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Spring manual, chapter 9.8: [Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj)

Answer (score 2):

Method calls from within classes will not work with proxy-based AOP.

Since you are using the keyword `this` (which is a pointer to your original object and not the proxy objects that is wrapping it), you will be calling the wrapped method directly - thus bypassing the code added as a result of your AOP.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will have to think of an alternative for calls to methods inside a class.

Comment: Nobody said anything about proxy-based AOP in the original question. Check out my own answer.